# Find objects by Tag value with Docx4j

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, docx4j

I am using Docx4J and have trouble finding objects i my template. I want to find ojbects preferably by "tags" and then edit the content within the SDT.

Example XML:

```
<w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
        <w:tag w:val="my_tag_key"/> <-- My key I want to use to find
        <w:id w:val="-2013140027"/>
        <w:placeholder>
            <w:docPart w:val="B7EA0BE1A23B43B3862BD5F3F1C831D0"/>
        </w:placeholder>
        <w:text/>
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtEndPr/>
    <w:sdtContent> <-- If no sdtContent exist I want to add new sdtContet with text
        <w:p w14:paraId="3F25D545" w14:textId="2589E674" w:rsidR="006E5249" w:rsidRPr="006E5249" w:rsidRDefault="00DB5DAC" w:rsidP="006E5249">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Tabelltext"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>I want to edit this text</w:t> <-- If  text exist I want to edit this
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:sdtContent>
</w:sdt>
```

I've tried to find object different ways for example by this method:

```
public static List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {
        var result = new ArrayList<Object>();
        if (obj instanceof JAXBElement) {
            obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();
        }
        if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch)) {
            result.add(obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {
            List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();
            for (Object child : children) {
                result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
            }
        } else if (obj instanceof SdtElement) {
            List<?> children = getAllElementFromObject(((SdtElement) obj).getSdtContent(), toSearch);
            for (Object child : children) {
                result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Tried to find SdtBlock, SdtContent, SdtContentCell etc but it does not work. I feel there must be a smarter way.

Comment: You should add some diagnostics to debug your method.  Alternatively, there is https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_11_4_8/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/finders/SdtFinder.java  For an idea of how to use it, see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_11_4_8/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/TraverseFind.java